# Need to execute sql queries over xml data

Tags: java, sql, xml, xml-parsing

Currently we have several queries, data of which we fetch from db and store it in memory. Now for the same queries we need a way to fetch data from xml rather than db server, i.e the data would be in xml in the below form:

```
    <?xml version='1.0'  encoding='Cp1252' ?>
    <tables>
    <TableOne>
    <Row1>
    <Column1>TableOne Row1 Column1 Value</Column1>
    <Column2>TableOne Row1 Column2 Value</Column2>
    <Column3>TableOne Row1 Column3 Value</Column3>
    </Row1>
    <Row2>
    <Column1>TableOne Row2 Column1 Value</Column1>
    <Column2>TableOne Row2 Column2 Value</Column2>
    <Column3>TableOne Row2 Column3 Value</Column3>
    </Row2>
    </TableOne>
    <TableTwo>
    <TableTwoRow1>
    <TableTwoRow1Column1>TableOne Row1 Column1 Value</TableTwoRow1Column1>
    <TableTwoRow1Column2>TableTwoRow1 Column2 Value</TableTwoRow1Column2>
    <TableTwoRow1Column3>TableTwoRow1 Column3 Value</TableTwoRow1Column3>
    </TableTwoRow1>
    <TableTwoRow2>
    <TableTwoRow2Column1>TableTwoRow2 Column1 Value</TableTwoRow2Column1>
    <TableTwoRow2Column2>TableTwoRow2 Column2 Value</TableTwoRow2Column2>
    <TableTwoRow2Column3>TableTwoRow2 Column3 Value</TableTwoRow2Column3>
    </TableTwoRow2>
    </TableTwo>
    </tables>
```

To achieve the above functionality I have made my own data structure to store the above xml:

```
    public class DataObject {

    Map<String, Table> tables = new HashMap<String, Table>();

    public Map<String, Table> getTables() {
    return tables;
}

public void setTable(Map<String, Table> table) {
    this.tables = table;
}

    }
```

and then the Table would look like below:

```
    public class Table {

private String tableName;
private List<Map<String,String>> rowList = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

public Table(String tableName) {
    super();
    this.tableName = tableName;
}

public List<Map<String, String>> getRowList() {
    return rowList;
}

public void setRowList(List<Map<String, String>> rowList) {
    this.rowList = rowList;
}

public String getTableName() {
    return tableName;
}

public void setTableName(String tableName) {
    this.tableName = tableName;
}
```

}

Each row would be represented as Map and multiple rows would be represented as List. I have been able to put across the data from xml to the above 'DataObject' as below:

private DataObject getDataObject(Document document) {

```
    DataObject dataObject = new DataObject();

    Element rootElement = document.getRootElement();
    List<Element> tableList = rootElement.getChildren();

    for (Element tableElement : tableList) {

        String tableName = tableElement.getName();
        Table table = new Table(tableName);
        dataObject.getTables().put(tableName, table);
        List<Element> rows = tableElement.getChildren();

        for (Element rowElement : rows) {

            Map<String, String> row = new HashMap<String, String>();

            List<Element> columns = rowElement.getChildren();
            for (Element columnElement : columns) {
                String columnName = columnElement.getName();
                String columnValue = columnElement.getValue();
                row.put(columnName, columnValue);
            }

            table.getRowList().add(row);
        }
    }

    return dataObject;

}
```

Now I can't think of an efficient way to query the above dataObject to execute the queries and I can't find any inbuilt API that would help me do that. The queries would have select, group by, order by and all logical operators.
Any thoughts would really be appreciated.

Comment: Why? A database is the perfect tool for this job, and you already have one. Why not keep using it?

Comment: No doubt, we will be using database. But as an extra functionality this feature has been introduced to support xml based data as well!

Comment: If your objective is to store data in RAM and present it, it might be worth your while to look at something designed for that, like qlikview.

Comment: Use an in-memory database engine.  Even SQLite sounds good enough for your needs.  There are many ways you can push your xml data into the SQLite tables, then your existing SQL should continue to work.  Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @MatBailie The xml data would consist of different table consisting of different columns which can't be anticipated beforehand. Could you please suggest me how would I map my generic data to SQLLite?

Comment: @MatBailie Sqlite seems to be a good solution that would cater my requirement. Thanks a lot for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

Why SQL? Consider the other special-purpose declarative language designed specifically for XML: [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/). And Java ships with an XSLT 1.0 processor and still external processors for XSLT 2.0 and 3.0 including [Xalan and Saxon](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) run in Java. In XSLT, you can find most of your SQL counterparts as documents can be transformed according to XPath expressions, template processing, and basic logic and arithmetic operations. Notice XSLT scripts are well-formed XML files (with special instructions)!

Below is an example using the top 20 Stackoverflow users as of one week in August 2015. Examples are shown of the counterpart SQL in XSLT. In this example *topusers* would be the table and its children would be columns. Our good friend @JB Nizet who commented above is included in the XML!

**XML** Source

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<stackoverflow>
  <topusers>
    <user>Gordon Linoff</user>
    <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff</link>
    <goldbadges>18</goldbadges>
    <silverbadges>81</silverbadges>
    <bronzebadges>134</bronzebadges>
    <membership>3 years, 6 months</membership>
    <yearRank>#1</yearRank>
    <totalReputation>320356</totalReputation>
    <yearReputation>72008</yearReputation>
    <topskill>sql</topskill>
  </topusers>
  <topusers>
    <user>Martijn Pieters</user>
    <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters</link>
    <goldbadges>36</goldbadges>
    <silverbadges>787</silverbadges>
    <bronzebadges>975</bronzebadges>
    <membership>6 years, 3 months</membership>
    <yearRank>#2</yearRank>
    <totalReputation>385697</totalReputation>
    <yearReputation>66886</yearReputation>
    <topskill>python</topskill>
  </topusers>
  <topusers>
    <user>anubhava</user>
    <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava</link>
    <goldbadges>25</goldbadges>
    <silverbadges>100</silverbadges>
    <bronzebadges>173</bronzebadges>
    <membership>4 years, 7 months</membership>
    <yearRank>#3</yearRank>
    <totalReputation>279930</totalReputation>
    <yearReputation>62759</yearReputation>
    <topskill>regex</topskill>
  </topusers>
  <topusers>
    <user>Jon Skeet</user>
    <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet</link>
    <goldbadges>379</goldbadges>
    <silverbadges>5537</silverbadges>
    <bronzebadges>6720</bronzebadges>
    <membership>6 years, 10 months</membership>
    <yearRank>#4</yearRank>
    <totalReputation>797069</totalReputation>
    <yearReputation>57963</yearReputation>
    <topskill>c#</topskill>
  </topusers>
  <topusers>
    <user>akrun</user>
    <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun</link>
    <goldbadges>5</goldbadges>
    <silverbadges>25</silverbadges>
    <bronzebadges>58</bronzebadges>
    <membership>1 year, 1 month</membership>
    <yearRank>#5</yearRank>
    <totalReputation>88928</totalReputation>
    <yearReputation>57384</yearReputation>
    <topskill>r</topskill>
  </topusers>
  <topusers>
    <user>VonC</user>
    <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc</link>
    <goldbadges>131</goldbadges>
    <silverbadges>1354</silverbadges>
    <bronzebadges>1447</bronzebadges>
    <membership>6 years, 10 months</membership>
    <yearRank>#6</yearRank>
    <totalReputation>512007</totalReputation>
    <yearReputation>56260</yearReputation>
    <topskill>git</topskill>
  </topusers>
  <topusers>
    <user>CommonsWare</user>
    <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware</link>
    <goldbadges>53</goldbadges>
    <silverbadges>1104</silverbadges>
    <bronzebadges>1155</bronzebadges>
    <membership>6 years, 2 months</membership>
    <yearRank>#7</yearRank>
    <totalReputation>487584</totalReputation>
    <yearReputation>54921</yearReputation>
    <topskill>android</topskill>
  </topusers>
  <topusers>
    <user>T.J. Crowder</user>
    <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder</link>
    <goldbadges>51</goldbadges>
    <silverbadges>556</silverbadges>
    <bronzebadges>692</bronzebadges>
    <membership>5 years, 11 months</membership>
    <yearRank>#8</yearRank>
    <totalReputation>374425</totalReputation>
    <yearReputation>54121</yearReputation>
    <topskill>javascript</topskill>
  </topusers>
  <topusers>
    <user>Hans Passant</user>
    <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant</link>
    <goldbadges>62</goldbadges>
    <silverbadges>679</silverbadges>
    <bronzebadges>1277</bronzebadges>
    <membership>6 years, 10 months</membership>
    <yearRank>#9</yearRank>
    <totalReputation>565002</totalReputation>
    <yearReputation>53886</yearReputation>
    <topskill>c#</topskill>
  </topusers>
  <topusers>
    <user>BalusC</user>
    <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc</link>
    <goldbadges>148</goldbadges>
    <silverbadges>1925</silverbadges>
    <bronzebadges>2235</bronzebadges>
    <membership>5 years, 11 months</membership>
    <yearRank>#10</yearRank>
    <totalReputation>584857</totalReputation>
    <yearReputation>53693</yearReputation>
    <topskill>java</topskill>
  </topusers>
  <topusers>
    <user>dasblinkenlight</user>
    <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/335858/dasblinkenlight</link>
    <goldbadges>31</goldbadges>
    <silverbadges>342</silverbadges>
    <bronzebadges>617</bronzebadges>
    <membership>5 years, 3 months</membership>
    <yearRank>#11</yearRank>
    <totalReputation>354707</totalReputation>
    <yearReputation>52779</yearReputation>
    <topskill>java</topskill>
  </topusers>
  <topusers>
    <user>Eran</user>
    <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/1221571/eran</link>
    <goldbadges>18</goldbadges>
    <silverbadges>114</silverbadges>
    <bronzebadges>187</bronzebadges>
    <membership>3 years, 5 months</membership>
    <yearRank>#12</yearRank>
    <totalReputation>105090</totalReputation>
    <yearReputation>49529</yearReputation>
    <topskill>java</topskill>
  </topusers>
  <topusers>
    <user>Avinash Raj</user>
    <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/3297613/avinash-raj</link>
    <goldbadges>6</goldbadges>
    <silverbadges>25</silverbadges>
    <bronzebadges>59</bronzebadges>
    <membership>1 year, 5 months</membership>
    <yearRank>#13</yearRank>
    <totalReputation>96627</totalReputation>
    <yearReputation>48928</yearReputation>
    <topskill>regex</topskill>
  </topusers>
  <topusers>
    <user>Arun P Johny</user>
    <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/114251/arun-p-johny</link>
    <goldbadges>30</goldbadges>
    <silverbadges>194</silverbadges>
    <bronzebadges>254</bronzebadges>
    <membership>6 years, 2 months</membership>
    <yearRank>#14</yearRank>
    <totalReputation>218919</totalReputation>
    <yearReputation>45858</yearReputation>
    <topskill>jquery</topskill>
  </topusers>
  <topusers>
    <user>Alex Martelli</user>
    <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/95810/alex-martelli</link>
    <goldbadges>64</goldbadges>
    <silverbadges>752</silverbadges>
    <bronzebadges>1056</bronzebadges>
    <membership>6 years, 3 months</membership>
    <yearRank>#15</yearRank>
    <totalReputation>402886</totalReputation>
    <yearReputation>44772</yearReputation>
    <topskill>python</topskill>
  </topusers>
  <topusers>
    <user>unutbu</user>
    <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/190597/unutbu</link>
    <goldbadges>28</goldbadges>
    <silverbadges>473</silverbadges>
    <bronzebadges>617</bronzebadges>
    <membership>5 years, 9 months</membership>
    <yearRank>#16</yearRank>
    <totalReputation>295951</totalReputation>
    <yearReputation>44389</yearReputation>
    <topskill>python</topskill>
  </topusers>
  <topusers>
    <user>JB Nizet</user>
    <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet</link>
    <goldbadges>22</goldbadges>
    <silverbadges>307</silverbadges>
    <bronzebadges>491</bronzebadges>
    <membership>4 years, 6 months</membership>
    <yearRank>#17</yearRank>
    <totalReputation>319659</totalReputation>
    <yearReputation>43697</yearReputation>
    <topskill>java</topskill>
  </topusers>
  <topusers>
    <user>Quentin</user>
    <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin</link>
    <goldbadges>42</goldbadges>
    <silverbadges>491</silverbadges>
    <bronzebadges>664</bronzebadges>
    <membership>6 years, 10 months</membership>
    <yearRank>#18</yearRank>
    <totalReputation>397762</totalReputation>
    <yearReputation>43626</yearReputation>
    <topskill>javascript</topskill>
  </topusers>
  <topusers>
    <user>Darin Dimitrov</user>
    <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov</link>
    <goldbadges>108</goldbadges>
    <silverbadges>2089</silverbadges>
    <bronzebadges>2107</bronzebadges>
    <membership>6 years, 9 months</membership>
    <yearRank>#19</yearRank>
    <totalReputation>604319</totalReputation>
    <yearReputation>43621</yearReputation>
    <topskill>c#</topskill>
  </topusers>
  <topusers>
    <user>alecxe</user>
    <link>https://stackoverflow.com/users/771848/alecxe</link>
    <goldbadges>19</goldbadges>
    <silverbadges>108</silverbadges>
    <bronzebadges>194</bronzebadges>
    <membership>4 years, 2 months</membership>
    <yearRank>#20</yearRank>
    <totalReputation>116413</totalReputation>
    <yearReputation>42215</yearReputation>
    <topskill>python</topskill>
  </topusers>
</stackoverflow>
```

**SELECT** statement

```sql
SELECT User, Membership, Link
FROM topusers
WHERE topskill = 'Java'
```

```xml
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/stackoverflow">
    <xsl:copy>      
      <xsl:apply-templates select="topusers[topskill='java']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="topusers">
    <xsl:copy>      
      <xsl:copy-of select="user"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="membership"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="link"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**GROUP BY**

```sql
SELECT topskill AS skill, SUM(goldbadges) AS SumOfGoldBadges,     
       SUM(silverbadges) AS SumOfSilverBadges, SUM(bronzebadges) AS SumOfBronzeBadges, 
       AVG(totalReputation) AS AvgOfReps,
       Min(yearReputation) As MinOfYrReps, Max(yearReputation) As MaxOfYrReps
FROM topUsers
GROUP BY topskill
```

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
               xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="skillkey" match="topusers" use="topskill" />

  <xsl:template match="/stackoverflow">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="topusers[generate-id() = generate-id(key('skillkey', topskill)[1])]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Muenchian Method -->
  <xsl:template match="topusers">
    <xsl:variable name="curr-group" select="key('skillkey', topskill)" />

    <skill_group>      
      <skill><xsl:value-of select="$curr-group/topskill"/></skill>
      <SumOfGoldBadges><xsl:value-of select="sum($curr-group/goldbadges)"/></SumOfGoldBadges>
      <SumOfSilverBadges><xsl:value-of select="sum($curr-group/silverbadges)"/></SumOfSilverBadges>
      <SumOfBronzeBadges><xsl:value-of select="sum($curr-group/bronzebadges)"/></SumOfBronzeBadges>
      <AvgOfReps><xsl:value-of select="sum($curr-group/totalReputation)
                                            div count($curr-group/totalReputation)"/></AvgOfReps>

         <xsl:variable name="repsSorted">
              <xsl:for-each select="$curr-group">
                  <xsl:sort select="yearReputation" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
                  <xsl:copy-of select="yearReputation"/>
              </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:variable name="repsSortedSet" select="exsl:node-set($repsSorted)/yearReputation" />

      <MinOfYrReps><xsl:value-of select="$repsSortedSet[1]"/></MinOfYrReps>
      <MaxOfYrReps><xsl:value-of select="$repsSortedSet[last()]"/></MaxOfYrReps>        
    </skill_group>    
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**ORDER BY**

```sql
SELECT * FROM topusers
ORDER BY goldbages DESC
```

```xml
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Identity Transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="stackoverflow">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="topusers">
        <xsl:sort select="goldbadges" order="descending" data-type="number"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**CASE/WHEN**

```sql
SELECT user, membership, link,  
       CASE 
            WHEN membership LIKE '%1 year%' OR membership LIKE '%2 years%'
                 OR membership LIKE '%3 years%'
            THEN 'recent member'
            WHEN membership LIKE '%4 years%' OR membership LIKE '%5 years%'
            THEN 'mid member'
            ELSE 'long member'
       END AS member_type
FROM topusers
```

```xml
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/stackoverflow">
    <xsl:copy>      
      <xsl:apply-templates select="topusers"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="topusers">
    <xsl:copy>      
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(membership, '1 year') or contains(membership, '2 years')
                        or contains(membership, '3 years')">          
            <xsl:copy-of select="user"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="membership"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="link"/>
            <member_type>recent member</member_type>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains(membership, '4 years') or contains(membership, '5 years')">                      
            <xsl:copy-of select="user"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="membership"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="link"/>
            <member_type>mid member</member_type>
        </xsl:when>  
        <xsl:otherwise>                      
            <xsl:copy-of select="user"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="membership"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="link"/>
            <member_type>long member</member_type>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Java** *(to run an XSLT script on XML source)*

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;

import java.io.*;    
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class CourseList {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException,
                                                  SAXException, ParserConfigurationException,
                                                  TransformerException {

            // Load XML and XSL Document
            String inputXML = "/path/to/Input.xml";
            String xslFile = "/path/to/XSLT/Script.xsl";
            String outputXML = "/path/to/Output.xml";

            Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File(xslFile));            
            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();            
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse (new File(inputXML));

            // XSLT Transformation with pretty print
            TransformerFactory prettyPrint = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = prettyPrint.newTransformer(xslt);

            // Dynamic XSLT
            String root = "stackoverflow";
            String TableName = "topusers";
            String Column1 = "user";
            String Column2 = "membership";
            String Column3 = "link";
            String Column4 = "topskill";
            String wherevalue = "java";

            String xslStr = String.join("\n",
                "<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\" version=\"1.0\">",
                "<xsl:output version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" indent=\"yes\" />",
                "<xsl:strip-space elements=\"*\"/> ",
                "  <xsl:template match=\"/"+root+"\">",
                "    <xsl:copy>",
                "      <xsl:apply-templates select=\""+TableName+"["+Column4+"='"+wherevalue+"']\"/>",
                "    </xsl:copy>",
                "  </xsl:template>",
                "  <xsl:template match=\""+TableName+"\">",
                "    <xsl:copy>",
                "      <xsl:copy-of select=\""+Column1+"\"/>",
                "      <xsl:copy-of select=\""+Column2+"\"/>",
                "      <xsl:copy-of select=\""+Column3+"\"/>",
                "    </xsl:copy>",
                "  </xsl:template>",
                "</xsl:transform>");

            // Parse XSLT String and Configure Transformer
            Source xslt = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xslStr));
            TransformerFactory prettyPrint = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
            Transformer transformer = prettyPrint.newTransformer(xslt);

            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.STANDALONE, "yes");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
            transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");                        

            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(outputXML));        
            transformer.transform(source, result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for introducing me to an entirely new and wonderful concept that I wasn't aware about. I have now read about XSLT, I am afraid I can't see it to fit to my requirement. The xml data could contain any table and any column and thus would be different every time. Moreover no query can be anticipated beforehand so I can't see making the .xsl file could be feasible. I would really appreciate if you could let me know where I might have got this wrong. Thanks!

Comment: I would not even know how you could anticipate *any* table with *any* column (of *any* type) and *any* query in SQL! Machine learning? You can embed XSLT inside your Java code as a string variable and hence dynamically change it as needed. See edited Java code using the `SELECT` script. So, the best I see is you build templated strings with placeholders and concatenate the table/column names to the string.